# Не работает .one

Tags: jquery, opera, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Код:

```
$('body').one("scroll", function() {
                myfunc(); 
            });
```

работает в IE и не работает во всем остальном.
Как правильно сделать, чтобы работало во всех браузера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понятное дело. Вы на body разве вешали css-правило overflow: scroll? А даже если и повесили, то могло все равно ничего не получиться.

```
function myfunc() {
    alert('UpS!');
}
$(document).one('scroll', myfunc);
```

Comment: да, в осталдьных заработало.
...только в IE перестало

Comment: Вот так уже должно везде работать:

    $(window).one('scroll', myfunc);